# Scraping data from JavaScript-powered website

Tags: php, web-scraping

I want to scrape data from http://www.ifanca.org/Pages/Certified-Products.aspx?search=22535. This is my PHP script:

```
<?php
 //get the html returned from the following url
$html = file_get_contents(
  'http://www.ifanca.org/Pages/Certified-Products.aspx?search=22535');

$pokemon_doc = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); //disable libxml errors

if(!empty($html)) { //if any html is actually returned

  $pokemon_doc->loadHTML($html);
  libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors for yucky html

  $pokemon_xpath = new DOMXPath($pokemon_doc);

  $pokemon_row = $pokemon_xpath->query('//*[@id="example"]');

  if($pokemon_row->length > 0){
    foreach($pokemon_row as $row){
      echo $row->nodeValue . "<br/>";
    }
  }
}
?>
```

It gives me the result:

> Product Name Company Name Sold In Marketing Type Product Type Product Code Logo Ifanca Code

which is fine. But when I am trying to get product name e.g "4Life Transfer Factor Belle Vie" by quering `//*[@id="example"]/tbody/tr/td[1]` then it gives me nothing.

[image: Screenshot]

I need help to get Product Name data.

Comment: Did one of the below answers solve the problem here, Kamran? If so, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

If you `wget` the file and examine it’s content, you’ll find that everything is being fulfilled with the javascript, while initial HTML of the table is:

```
<table id="example" class="display"  
       width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">

  <thead>
    <tr><th width="22%" style="width:22% !important">Company Name </th>
        <th width="13%" style="width:13% !important">Sold In</th>
        <th width="23%" style="width:23% !important">Product Name</th>h>
        <th width="22%" style="width:22% !important">Company Name </th>
        <th width="13%" style="width:13% !important">Sold In</th></th>
        <th width="10%" style="width:10% !important">Marketing Type</th>
        <th width="10%" style="width:10% !important">Product Type</th>
        <th width="10%" style="width:10% !important">Product Code</th>
        <th width="5%" style="width:5% !important" >Logo</th>
        <th width="7%" style="width:7% !important">Ifanca Code</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Neither `file_get_contents` nor `DOMDocument` would parse and execute javascript for you. That’s why you harvest an empty resultset for

```
//*[@id="example"]/tbody/tr/td[1]
```

it is simply not existing in the resulting document.

Comment: mudasobwa, how can i get Product Name data? Is there any alternative ?

Comment: @KamranUllah NodeJS and run coming javascript manually (but there might be other glitches as well.)

Answer (score 1):

This site is dependent on JavaScript. If you open your Network developer tools (in Firefox and probably most other browsers) when the page loads, you'll see it generates four AJAX POST requests to the server. It is likely that each of these are dependent on the other, so it may not be trivial to scrape these.

Normally I recommend scraping AJAX GET requests, since there is (and should be) only one per data source, but this site is fetching content in a way that is wasteful of HTTP resources and in a way that is hard to scrape. Indeed, that may be the reason why the developers did it this way - they don't want other people to republish their information.

The input parameters of one of the requests take this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/clientquery/2009" SchemaVersion="15.0.0.0" LibraryVersion="15.0.0.0" ApplicationName="Javascript Library">
   <Actions>
      <ObjectPath Id="1" ObjectPathId="0" />
      <ObjectPath Id="3" ObjectPathId="2" />
      <ObjectPath Id="5" ObjectPathId="4" />
      <ObjectPath Id="7" ObjectPathId="6" />
      <ObjectIdentityQuery Id="8" ObjectPathId="6" />
      <ObjectPath Id="10" ObjectPathId="9" />
      <ObjectPath Id="12" ObjectPathId="11" />
      <ObjectIdentityQuery Id="13" ObjectPathId="11" />
      <ObjectPath Id="15" ObjectPathId="14" />
      <Query Id="16" ObjectPathId="9">
         <Query SelectAllProperties="true">
            <Properties />
         </Query>
         <ChildItemQuery SelectAllProperties="true">
            <Properties />
         </ChildItemQuery>
      </Query>
   </Actions>
   <ObjectPaths>
      <StaticProperty Id="0" TypeId="{3747adcd-a3c3-41b9-bfab-4a64dd2f1e0a}" Name="Current" />
      <Property Id="2" ParentId="0" Name="Web" />
      <Property Id="4" ParentId="2" Name="Lists" />
      <Method Id="6" ParentId="4" Name="GetByTitle">
         <Parameters>
            <Parameter Type="String">HCM</Parameter>
         </Parameters>
      </Method>
      <Method Id="9" ParentId="6" Name="GetItems">
         <Parameters>
            <Parameter TypeId="{3d248d7b-fc86-40a3-aa97-02a75d69fb8a}">
               <Property Name="DatesInUtc" Type="Boolean">true</Property>
               <Property Name="FolderServerRelativeUrl" Type="Null" />
               <Property Name="ListItemCollectionPosition" Type="Null" />
               <Property Name="ViewXml" Type="String">&lt;View Scope="RecursiveAll"&gt;&lt;Query&gt;&lt;Where&gt;&lt;And&gt;&lt;IsNotNull&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name="Year"/&gt;&lt;/IsNotNull&gt;&lt;In&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name="FileType"/&gt;&lt;Values&gt;&lt;Value Type="Choice"&gt;Image&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;Value Type="Choice"&gt;Flipbook&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;Value Type="Choice"&gt;pdf&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Values&gt;&lt;/In&gt;&lt;/And&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;&lt;OrderBy&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name="IssueNo" Ascending="False" /&gt;&lt;/OrderBy&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;RowLimit&gt;10&lt;/RowLimit&gt;&lt;/View&gt;</Property>
            </Parameter>
         </Parameters>
      </Method>
      <Method Id="11" ParentId="4" Name="GetByTitle">
         <Parameters>
            <Parameter Type="String">HDNL</Parameter>
         </Parameters>
      </Method>
      <Method Id="14" ParentId="11" Name="GetItems">
         <Parameters>
            <Parameter TypeId="{3d248d7b-fc86-40a3-aa97-02a75d69fb8a}">
               <Property Name="DatesInUtc" Type="Boolean">true</Property>
               <Property Name="FolderServerRelativeUrl" Type="Null" />
               <Property Name="ListItemCollectionPosition" Type="Null" />
               <Property Name="ViewXml" Type="String">&lt;View Scope="RecursiveAll"&gt;&lt;Query&gt;&lt;Where&gt;&lt;IsNotNull&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name="YYYY"/&gt;&lt;/IsNotNull&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;&lt;OrderBy&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name="IssueNumber" Ascending="False" /&gt;&lt;/OrderBy&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;RowLimit&gt;3&lt;/RowLimit&gt;&lt;/View&gt;</Property>
            </Parameter>
         </Parameters>
      </Method>
   </ObjectPaths>
</Request>
```

Yikes! If you want to build requests that way and scrape by sending a similar document, then you'd have to work out the format. I suspect here it would be much easier to use a headless browser, such as PhantomJS. There are PHP drivers for this, such as [Spiderling](https://github.com/OpenBuildings/spiderling). That will run the JavaScript for you (on a modern Webkit browser) and you'll be able to retrieve your data using an XPath or CSS selector.

(Remember that data on other sites may be subject to copyright. You could go to the trouble of setting up a scraper only to find that you are the target of an IP block, or worse still, legal action. The rights and wrongs of scraping are rather complicated, but my brief advice is if you can scrape from a range of targets, it makes your project less susceptible to failure).

Comment: thanks for explanation. Well, i am trying to use Spiderling PHP driver. Currently i am using window 8.1 and  WAMP. I have downloaded  https://github.com/OpenBuildings/spiderling and put it into the root directory of WAMP. How can i use/configure spiderling ? Please provide me some step-wise procedure/guideline or refer me some basic tutorial.

Comment: See "A quick example" in that link, @KamranUllah. Tutorials don't come more basic than that! (If you have used Composer it should get PhantomJS for you, if not you will have to install that yourself).

Comment: Ah, I think that might have been mistaken - you have to install PhantomJS yourself. Just set it up so you can call `phantomjs` at the console. This should be as easy as running the installer and setting up the `PATH`, as is usual for Windows console programs.

Comment: @ halfer sir, i have installed Phantomjs and test it. It's working fine  for me. But i am confuse a bit that where can i place the "A quick example" code. I have created a file in which i put the code of "a quick example". Now where i place the file as it is not mention in the example.

Comment: @Kamran: put it in a file in whatever directory you like, and call it with `php` just as you would have done with your own. You can `cd` to that folder and then run `php myscript.php`.

Comment: sir, then what is the link between Phantomjs and Spiderling PHP driver. Why we need Phantomjs for Spiderling ???

Comment: @Kamran: PhantomJS contains a JavaScript-capable browser. Spiderling is a library to make it convenient to use in PHP. You can use Spiderling without PhantomJS, but we've established that this particular page needs JavaScript, so you'd be stuck without PhantomJS (or some other headless browser).

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue by using DIFFBOT Article API and the link of API is https://www.diffbot.com.